# gcc error-messages crippled (code-page or encoding-problem)

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

I use debian and g++. When compiling i get error-messages like these:

**In static member function ΓÇÿstatic void* v4::_mb_blocs::operator new(size_t)ΓÇÖ:**

Can i tell gcc to do its output in utf-8 or something ?

Comment: Ehm, ok: Just to clarify this, its the double-quotes i want to see instead of the ΓÇÿ thats all, so its just some sort of cosmetic, but it still makes the messages sort of unreadable to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally gcc outputs in ASCII or UTF-8, so you should check if your terminal is actually configured for UTF-8 (`locale charmap`).

Also try:

```
LC_ALL=C LANG=C gcc
```

to get ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your console font.